# How to disable the jetty icon in Jetty11

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

I am updating Jetty9 to Jetty11 and need to know that how to disable the server icon in Jetty11.
I used to do the below changes on the etc\jetty.XML for Jetty9.

```
<New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler">
            <Set name="serveIcon">false</Set>
</New>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is just to make your own `favicon.ico` and put in in your ROOT context as a static file to serve.

Otherwise, if you want to tweak the existing `id="DefaultHandler"` component with your `${jetty.base}` take a look at this example `${jetty.base}` ...

```
$ tree -F no-favico-base/
no-favico-base/
├── etc/
│   └── tweak-defaulthandler.xml
├── resources/
│   └── jetty-logging.properties
├── start.d/
│   ├── deploy.ini
│   ├── http.ini
│   └── tweaks.ini
└── webapps/

4 directories, 5 files
```

It has 2 files that are used to accomplish this.

**etc/tweak-defaulthandler.xml**

```xml
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
          "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_10.dtd">
<Configure id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler">
  <Set name="serveIcon">false</Set>
</Configure>
```

Which configures the existing `id="DefaultHandler"` that was previously defined in the `${jetty.home}/etc/jetty.xml`.

And an ini to add this xml to the configuration.
This name can be anything you want, I just chose "tweak" as I like to put all of the tweaks I make in this one ini.

**start.d/tweak.ini**

```
etc/tweak-defaulthandler.xml
```

You can see the order of the XML's being executed using `--list-config`

```sh
$ java -jar /opt/jetty/jetty-home-10.0.6/start.jar --list-config
...(snip)...
Jetty Active XMLs:
------------------
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-bytebufferpool.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-threadpool.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-webapp.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-deploy.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-http.xml
 ${jetty.base}/etc/tweak-defaulthandler.xml
```